# What order should I watch Nurarihyon no Mago in?

Tags: nurarihyon-no-mago

What order should I watch "Nurarihton no Mago" and "Nurarihyon no Mago - Sennen Makyou" in? Because I'm pretty sure the events from episode 1 of the latter of the 2 take place before the events in the former of the 2. So is that the correct order I should watch them in?

Answer (score 2):

In general, watching the anime in release order is the default recommendation, as also for this case:

1. *Nurarihyon no Mago*
2. *Nurarihyon no Mago: Sennen Makyou*

However, [Japanese Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%81%AC%E3%82%89%E3%82%8A%E3%81%B2%E3%82%87%E3%82%93%E3%81%AE%E5%AD%AB#%E5%8E%9F%E4%BD%9C%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89%E3%81%AE%E4%B8%BB%E3%81%AA%E5%A4%89%E6%9B%B4%E7%82%B9) notes the differences in the anime adaptation from the original manga:

> Session 1:
>
> - Episode 1 starts with the night-form of Rikuo confronting Gyuki on Mount Nejireme, then it continues to chapter 2 of the original manga.
> - [...]
>
> Session 2:
>
> - Episode 1 broadcasts chapter 1 of the original manga.
> - [...]

So, chronologically (or "more faithful manga order"):

1. **Season 2 Episode 1**
2. **Season 1 Episode 1**-24
3. **Season 2 Episode 2**-24